# Angular dategangepicker multiple buttons

Tags: angular, daterangepicker

I've used angular port of daterangepicker [original js library](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) 
The port used: [See here](https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker#readme)

i've got predefined buttons displayed multiple times: 
[image]

my code is based on following sandbox example : [In here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5l5r8o17)
ranges are displayed correctly.

Here is my code piece for HTML template:

```
<div class="datepicker form-group">
<div class="input-group"
    name="daterangeInput" 
    daterangepicker 
    [options]="options"                                         
    (applyDaterangepicker)="applyDate($event)"
>
    <span class="form-control uneditable-input ">
            {{ daterange.label  }}
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

The typescript options look like:

```
public daterange: any = {
   start: moment().subtract(6, 'days'),
   end: moment(),
   label: 'Last 7 days'
};

@ViewChild(DaterangePickerComponent)
private picker: DaterangePickerComponent;

public options: any = {
   locale: { format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' },
   alwaysShowCalendars: false,
   ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 90 Days': [moment().subtract(89, 'days'), moment()]
    }    
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/py4lr685mm

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: It's  working fine in given codesandbox url.

Comment: Thats right. @Shantanu. In my case there is no errors in the console. but the daterangepicker is displayed like on the image. Each button is fullyfunctional. I've just got the 3 columns of my buttons. Anys suggestion to test/debug is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems we are unable to reproduce this bug. What browser are you testing this with? I have noticed that the component's layout in Firefox differs from that in Chrome and Edge, though it is not broken.

Is this the complete HTML you are using? I have noticed that you are missing a closing DIV. Have you tried using the component in an otherwise clean environment to guarantee that it is not an error on your side?

At this point it could be worth considering to not use this library and/or to open [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker/issues).

Comment: Yes, the environment is cleaned up. Reproduced in chrome as well. i'll extend the html fragment soon

Comment: good point @Gordon Westerman [https://codesandbox.io/s/py4lr685mm] reproduced the issue in the sandbox. the issue is in the bad markdown

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Multiple  tags occured when compiling to the final codebase. THis causes the issue.